# Replace web.xml in Vaadin

Tags: servlets, vaadin, web.xml

I use Vaadin 7. I want to change the default `Servlet` in my application. What I did is the following :

```
public class MyVaadinApplication extends UI {

  @WebServlet(urlPatterns = "/*", asyncSupported = true)
  @VaadinServletConfiguration(productionMode = true, ui = MyVaadinApplication.class)
  public static class Servlet extends VaadinServlet {

   @Override
    public void init(ServletConfig servletConfig) throws ServletException {

      super.init(servletConfig);

      /*
       * Vaadin SessionListener
       */
       getService().addSessionInitListener(new VaadinSessionListener.VaadinSessionInitListener());
       getService().addSessionDestroyListener(new VaadinSessionListener.VaadinSessionDestroyListener());
     }
    }
  ....
```

It doesn't take in count the new servlet. I tried to remove Web.xml but I got an error.
How can I replace the Servlet inside the web.xml ?

Answer (score 0):

You should decide first which Servlet version your project is using.

If you want to use the @WebServlet annoations, you should configure your project using Servlet version 3.0.

In Eclipse under Project->Properties->Project Facets->Dynamic Web Module->3.0

Otherwise you have to add The "Servlet" class to your web.xml.

There is a description in the book of vaadin how to configure the web.xml (check chapter 4.8.4)

https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/application.environment.html

Comment: I already have properties set to Dynamic Web Module->3.0. And I have a web.xml well configured. but I don't what to work with web.xml I want to set the Servlet inside my UI.

Comment: did you check if the code in the Servlet.init() method is getting executed?

Comment: No it is not executed, it seems that my UI is ignoring the `Servlet` inner class.

Comment: If you are using maven, the servlet code should have been generated inside the UI on project creation. If you have inserted it manually, you could have done something wrong. if you can, please paste the whole code of the UI class somewhere. i can take a look.

Comment: What do you have within your web.xml. If I recall correcly, if you have the same options defined in web.xml as well as in annotations, then the web.xml takes priority. See if you have the servlet in web.xml and try to delete the part.